# What do these lines of code do?

Tags: php

I am working on modifying a plugin for wordpress to better suit my needs, and I need to know exactly what this code does:

```
if ( $single_download['uniqueid'] == null )
    $link[] = array( "url" => site_url( "?downloadid=" . $single_download['id'] ), "name" => $file_name );
else
    $link[] = array( "url" => site_url( "?downloadid=" . $single_download['uniqueid'] ), "name" => $file_name );
```

If you would need more than just this code here, could you please just explain what it is doing as far as you can tell by the scope of the code I have provided. I am assuming it is combining the different items but I am nut sure.

Edit: Sorry I should have clarified I realize what the if statement is doing, I need to know what the other line of code does.

Comment: Really really really need to know the plugin, and probably you should link to the full code - not just this snipit... along with their website.  Out of context, this could do anything.  - P.S. are there any comments in this code around this line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a statement populates an array (`$link`) with values based on the result of a test.

If the value of `$single_download['uniqueid']` is null, the value of $single_download['id'] is appended to a URL. If `$single_download['uniqueid']` is not null, its value is appended to the URL.

In both cases, the resultant value of the URL is inserted into the array.

Answer (score 0):

the code is constructing an array using one of two possible locations in the "single_download" variable to use for the download id

Answer (score 0):

It's just building the link array item based on whether there's a uniqueid or not.

I'm not familiar with the plugin, but the `$link` array apparently holds the url to download a file. If the `$single_download` array has a uniqueid key that is not null, then it uses that as the download id. Otherwise, it uses the value in the id key.

I'm assuming it creates a clickable link with the `url` as the source of the href and `name` is the text that is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to check for a uniqueid in $single_download and if it doesn't find it, it uses the "ID" instead of "UNIQUEID"

Thats all